How to create a Solana wallet in Java?
As title says, how do I create a Solana wallet in Java?
Using an example, I have created an RPC Client that checks out a public key's funds which prints out '9198260'
RpcClient client = new RpcClient(Cluster.TESTNET);
        
        try {
            long balance = client.getApi().getBalance(new PublicKey("QqCCvshxtqMAL2CVALqiJB7uEeE5mjSPsseQdDzsRUo"));
            System.out.println(balance);
        } catch (RpcException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

How can I create my own Solana wallet and add funds into it on the testnet?

Use the Solana PublicKey and Account classes from the Solana Java SDK to create a new Solana wallet.

You can do it with sol4k and the Keypair class:
var keypair = Keypair.generate();

Here are the Java examples. Find the details in the documentation.
